# Custom Access Denied Page in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-2010

I have used the following powershell instructions to update the custom AccessDenied page in my sharepoint portal:

```
$site = get-spsite "http://sure-intra:5566" 
$webApp =$site.WebApplication 
$webapp.UpdateMappedPage(1,"/_layouts/MyProject/AccessDenied.aspx") 
$webapp.Update()
```

I've received the following error:

> This error (HTTP 403 Forbidden)

I was able to connect to the website, but I do not have permission to view the webpage.

What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: Are you running the command shell with a farm admin account and as administrator?

Comment: I have two sharepoint front-end servers and two applications servers.
The PwoerShell is installed in application servers not in sharepoint servers.